# Check if FTP folder exists & if not then create it

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I need a function to complete the following tasks:

1. Check if a folder exists (via its name) - if not then, create it.
2. Upload a file into the directory.

I tried with the following code, but it does not seem to check and create the directory:

```
Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create("HOST"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("uase", "pass")
request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\Nini\Desktop\10ebd0d.png")
Dim str As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
str.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
str.Close()
str.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [FTPClient](http://netftp.codeplex.com/) library for `.NET`

I've did an helper Class to manage the library (but is easy as is provided there is no need to use an helper Class)

The methods that you're interested to are `DirectoryExists`, `CreateDirectory`, and `UploadFile`

This is an example usage:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents UploadClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
    Private WithEvents DownloadClient As New System.Net.WebClient()

    Private ftp As New FTP("ftpsite", "username", "password")

    Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown

        ftp.Connect()
        ftp.CreateDirectory("/DirectoryName", True)
        ftp.UploadFile(UploadClient, "C:\File.txt", "/DirectoryName/NewFile.txt", False)
        ftp.DownloadFile(DownloadClient, "/DirectoryName/NewFile.txt", "c:\DownloadedFile.txt", True)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Client_UploadProgress(sender As System.Net.WebClient, e As System.Net.UploadProgressChangedEventArgs) _
    Handles UploadClient.UploadProgressChanged

        Label_Upload.Text = e.ProgressPercentage & "%"

    End Sub

    Private Sub Client_UploadCompleted(sender As System.Net.WebClient, e As System.Net.UploadFileCompletedEventArgs) _
    Handles UploadClient.UploadFileCompleted

        Label_UploadCompleted.Text = e.Result.ToString

    End Sub

    Private Sub Client_DownloadProgress(sender As System.Net.WebClient, e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) _
    Handles DownloadClient.DownloadProgressChanged

        Label_Download.Text = e.ProgressPercentage & "%"

    End Sub

    Private Sub Client_DownloadCompleted(sender As System.Net.WebClient, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs) _
     Handles DownloadClient.DownloadFileCompleted

        Label_DownloadCompleted.Text = "Done!"

    End Sub

End Class
```

The Helper Class:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.FtpClient
Imports System.Net.FtpClient.Extensions

#Region " FTPClient Helper "

' [ FTPClient Helper ]
'
' // By Elektro


Public Class FTP

#Region " Variables "

    Private conn As New FtpClient

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The FTP site.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Property host As String = String.Empty

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The user name.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Property user As String = String.Empty

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The user password.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Property pass As String = String.Empty

    ' Friend m_reset As New ManualResetEvent(False) ' Use it for CallBacks

#End Region

#Region " Constructor "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' .
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="host">Indicates the ftp site.</param>
    ''' <param name="user">Indicates the username.</param>
    ''' <param name="pass">Indicates the password.</param>
    Public Sub New(ByVal host As String,
                   ByVal user As String,
                   ByVal pass As String)

        If Not host.ToLower.StartsWith("ftp://") Then
            Me.host = "ftp://" & host
        Else
            Me.host = host
        End If

        If Me.host.Last = "/" Then
            Me.host = Me.host.Remove(Me.host.Length - 1)
        End If

        Me.user = user
        Me.pass = pass

        With conn
            .Host = If(host.Last = "/", host.Remove(host.Length - 1), host)
            .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.user, Me.pass)
        End With

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Public Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Connects to server.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Connect()
        conn.Connect()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Disconnects from server.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Disconnect()
        conn.Disconnect()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a directory on server.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="directorypath">Indicates the ftp directory path.</param>
    ''' <param name="force">Try to force all non-existant pieces of the path to be created.</param>
    Public Sub CreateDirectory(ByVal directorypath As String, ByVal force As Boolean)
        conn.CreateDirectory(directorypath, force)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a directory on server.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="directorypath">Indicates the ftp directory path.</param>
    ''' <param name="force">Try to force all non-existant pieces of the path to be created.</param>
    ''' <param name="FtpListOption">Options that dictate how a list is performed ans what information is gathered.</param>
    Public Sub DeleteDirectory(ByVal directorypath As String,
                               ByVal force As Boolean,
                               Optional ByVal FtpListOption As FtpListOption =
                               FtpListOption.AllFiles Or FtpListOption.ForceList)

        ' Remove the directory and all objects beneath it. The last parameter
        ' forces System.Net.FtpClient to use LIST -a for getting a list of objects
        ' beneath the specified directory.
        conn.DeleteDirectory(directorypath, force, FtpListOption)

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Deletes a file on server.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    Public Sub DeleteFile(ByVal filepath As String)
        conn.DeleteFile(filepath)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Checks if a directory exist on server.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="directorypath">Indicates the ftp directory path.</param>
    Public Function DirectoryExists(ByVal directorypath As String) As Boolean
        Return conn.DirectoryExists(directorypath)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Executes a command on server.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="command">Indicates the command to execute on the server.</param>
    ''' <returns>Returns an object containing the server reply information.</returns>
    Public Function Execute(ByVal command As String) As FtpReply
        Return (InlineAssignHelper(New FtpReply, conn.Execute(command)))
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Tries to execute a command on server.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="command">Indicates the command to execute on the server.</param>
    ''' <returns>Returns TRUE if command execution successfull, otherwise returns False.</returns>
    Public Function TryExecute(ByVal command As String) As Boolean
        Dim reply As FtpReply = Nothing
        Return (InlineAssignHelper(reply, conn.Execute(command))).Success
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Checks if a file exist on server.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    ''' <param name="FtpListOption">Options that dictate how a list is performed ans what information is gathered.</param>
    Public Function FileExists(ByVal filepath As String,
                               Optional ByVal FtpListOption As FtpListOption =
                               FtpListOption.AllFiles Or FtpListOption.ForceList) As Boolean

        ' The last parameter forces System.Net.FtpClient to use LIST -a 
        ' for getting a list of objects in the parent directory.
        Return conn.FileExists(filepath, FtpListOption)

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Retrieves a checksum of the given file
    ''' using a checksumming method that the server supports, if any.
    ''' The algorithm used goes in this order: 
    ''' 1. HASH command (server preferred algorithm).
    ''' 2. MD5 / XMD5 commands 
    ''' 3. XSHA1 command 
    ''' 4. XSHA256 command 
    ''' 5. XSHA512 command
    ''' 6. XCRC command
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    Public Function GetChecksum(ByVal filepath As String) As FtpHash
        Return conn.GetChecksum(filepath)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the checksum of file on server and compare it with the checksum of local file.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    ''' <param name="localfilepath">Indicates the local disk file path.</param>
    ''' <param name="algorithm">Indicates the algorithm that should be used to verify checksums.</param>
    ''' <returns>Returns TRUE if both checksums are equal, otherwise returns False.</returns>
    Public Function VerifyChecksum(ByVal filepath As String,
                                   ByVal localfilepath As String,
                                   ByVal algorithm As FtpHashAlgorithm) As Boolean

        Dim hash As FtpHash = Nothing

        hash = conn.GetChecksum(filepath)
        ' Make sure it returned a, to the best of our knowledge, valid hash object. 
        ' The commands for retrieving checksums are
        ' non-standard extensions to the protocol so we have to
        ' presume that the response was in a format understood by
        ' System.Net.FtpClient and parsed correctly.
        '
        ' In addition, there is no built-in support for verifying CRC hashes. 
        ' You will need to write you own or use a third-party solution.
        If hash.IsValid AndAlso hash.Algorithm <> algorithm Then
            Return hash.Verify(localfilepath)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the size of file.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    Public Function GetFileSize(ByVal filepath As String) As Long
        Return conn.GetFileSize(filepath)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the currently HASH algorithm used for the HASH command on server.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Function GetHashAlgorithm() As FtpHashAlgorithm
        Return conn.GetHashAlgorithm()
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the modified time of file.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    Public Function GetModifiedTime(ByVal filepath As String) As Date
        Return conn.GetModifiedTime(filepath)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a file/directory listing using the NLST command.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="directorypath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    Public Function GetNameListing(ByVal directorypath As String) As String()
        Return conn.GetNameListing(directorypath)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the current working directory on server.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Function GetWorkingDirectory() As String
        Return conn.GetWorkingDirectory()
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Opens the specified file to be appended to...
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    Public Function OpenAppend(ByVal filepath As String) As IO.Stream
        Return conn.OpenAppend(filepath)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Opens the specified file for reading.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    Public Function OpenRead(ByVal filepath As String) As IO.Stream
        Return conn.OpenRead(filepath)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Opens the specified file for writing.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    Public Function OpenWrite(ByVal filepath As String) As IO.Stream
        Return conn.OpenWrite(filepath)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Rename a file on the server.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    ''' <param name="newfilepath">Indicates the new ftp file path.</param>
    Public Sub RenameFile(ByVal filepath As String, ByVal newfilepath As String)
        If conn.FileExists(filepath) Then
            conn.Rename(filepath, newfilepath)
        Else
            Throw New Exception(filepath & " File does not exist on server.")
        End If
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Rename a directory on the server.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="directorypath">Indicates the ftp file path.</param>
    ''' <param name="newdirectorypath">Indicates the new ftp file path.</param>
    Public Sub RenameDirectory(ByVal directorypath As String, ByVal newdirectorypath As String)
        If conn.DirectoryExists(directorypath) Then
            conn.Rename(directorypath, newdirectorypath)
        Else
            Throw New Exception(directorypath & " Directory does not exist on server.")
        End If
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Tells the server wich hash algorithm to use for the HASH command.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="algorithm">Indicates the HASH algorithm.</param>
    Public Function SetHashAlgorithm(ByVal algorithm As FtpHashAlgorithm) As Boolean
        If conn.HashAlgorithms.HasFlag(algorithm) Then
            conn.SetHashAlgorithm(algorithm)
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sets the working directory on the server.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="directorypath">Indicates the ftp directory path.</param>
    Public Sub SetWorkingDirectory(ByVal directorypath As String)
        conn.SetWorkingDirectory(directorypath)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a directory list on the specified path.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="directorypath">Indicates the ftp directory path.</param>
    ''' <param name="FtpListOption">Options that dictate how a list is performed ans what information is gathered.</param>
    Public Function GetDirectories(ByVal directorypath As String,
                                   Optional ByVal FtpListOption As FtpListOption =
                                   FtpListOption.AllFiles) As FtpListItem()

        Return conn.GetListing(directorypath, FtpListOption).
               Where(Function(item) item.Type = FtpFileSystemObjectType.Directory)

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a file list on the specified path.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="directorypath">Indicates the ftp directory path.</param>
    ''' <param name="FtpListOption">Options that dictate how a list is performed ans what information is gathered.</param>
    Public Function GetFiles(ByVal directorypath As String,
                             Optional ByVal FtpListOption As FtpListOption =
                             FtpListOption.AllFiles) As FtpListItem()

        Return conn.GetListing(directorypath, FtpListOption).
               Where(Function(item) item.Type = FtpFileSystemObjectType.File)

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a link list on the specified path.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="directorypath">Indicates the ftp directory path.</param>
    ''' <param name="FtpListOption">Options that dictate how a list is performed ans what information is gathered.</param>
    Public Function GetLinks(ByVal directorypath As String,
                             Optional ByVal FtpListOption As FtpListOption =
                             FtpListOption.AllFiles) As FtpListItem()

        Return conn.GetListing(directorypath, FtpListOption).
               Where(Function(item) item.Type = FtpFileSystemObjectType.Link)

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a file/folder list on the specified path.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="directorypath">Indicates the ftp directory path.</param>
    ''' <param name="FtpListOption">Options that dictate how a list is performed ans what information is gathered.</param>
    Public Function GetListing(ByVal directorypath As String,
                               Optional ByVal FtpListOption As FtpListOption =
                               FtpListOption.AllFiles) As FtpListItem()

        Return conn.GetListing(directorypath, FtpListOption)

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Log to a console window
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub LogToConsole()
        FtpTrace.AddListener(New ConsoleTraceListener())
        ' now use System.Net.FtpCLient as usual and the server transactions
        ' will be written to the Console window.
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Log to a text file
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the file where to save the log.</param>
    Public Sub LogToFile(ByVal filepath As String)
        FtpTrace.AddListener(New TextWriterTraceListener(filepath))
        ' now use System.Net.FtpCLient as usual and the server transactions
        ' will be written to the specified log file.
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Uploads a file to FTP.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="UploadClient">Indicates the WebClient object to upload the file.</param>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp fle path.</param>
    ''' <param name="localfilepath">Specifies the local path where to save the downloaded file.</param>
    ''' <param name="Asynchronous">Indicates whether the download should be an Asynchronous operation, 
    ''' to raise WebClient events.</param>
    Public Sub UploadFile(ByRef UploadClient As WebClient,
                          ByVal localfilepath As String,
                          Optional ByVal filepath As String = Nothing,
                          Optional ByVal Asynchronous As Boolean = False)

        If filepath Is Nothing Then
            filepath = Me.host & "/" & New IO.FileInfo(localfilepath).Name
        ElseIf filepath.StartsWith("/") Then
            filepath = Me.host & filepath
        Else
            filepath = Me.host & "/" & filepath
        End If

        With UploadClient
            .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.user, Me.pass)
            If Asynchronous Then
                .UploadFileAsync(New Uri(filepath), "STOR", localfilepath)
            Else
                .UploadFile(New Uri(filepath), "STOR", localfilepath)
            End If
        End With

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Downloads a file from FTP.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="DownloadClient">Indicates the WebClient object to download the file.</param>
    ''' <param name="filepath">Indicates the ftp fle path.</param>
    ''' <param name="localfilepath">Specifies the local path where to save the downloaded file.</param>
    ''' <param name="Asynchronous">Indicates whether the download should be an Asynchronous operation, 
    ''' to raise WebClient events.</param>
    Public Sub DownloadFile(ByRef DownloadClient As WebClient,
                            ByVal filepath As String,
                            ByVal localfilepath As String,
                            Optional ByVal Asynchronous As Boolean = False)

        If filepath.StartsWith("/") Then
            filepath = Me.host & filepath
        Else
            filepath = Me.host & "/" & filepath
        End If

        With DownloadClient
            .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.user, Me.pass)
            If Asynchronous Then
                .DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(filepath), localfilepath)
            Else
                .DownloadFile(New Uri(filepath), localfilepath)
            End If
        End With

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Miscellaneous methods "

    Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
        target = value
        Return value
    End Function

#End Region

End Class

#End Region
```

Comment: I added dll to my project,but has some problem , System.Net.FtpClient and System.Net.FtpClient.Extensions does not included successfuly

Comment: Sorry,progress handler does not work,(Client_UploadProgressClient_UploadProgress)

Answer (score 2):

1.Check if a folder exists (via its name) - if not then, create it.

I'll admit that this is not the most robust or elegant solution but I was OK with something 'quick and dirty' for the occasional one-off need that I have for this.

```
    Dim request As FtpWebRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp/parentfolder")
    Dim creds As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential("user", "pwd")
    request.Credentials = creds

    Dim resp As FtpWebResponse = Nothing
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
    request.KeepAlive = True
        Using resp
            resp = request.GetResponse()
            Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
            Dim s As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
        If Not s.Contains("newfolder") Then

            request = FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp/parentfolder/newfolder")
            request.Credentials = creds
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory
            resp = request.GetResponse()
            Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode & "Created")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Directory already exists")
        End If
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Using
```

Comment: Works quite fine with just one exception. The first FtpWebRequest.Create must point at the root and the second one at the new folder. Example: FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp/parentfolder/") and the second would be FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp/parentfolder/newfolder")